# How to properly organize repository with big files which are rarely or never changed?

Tags: git, github

I just started to use git and github. I have a big json-file (~45Mb). It is used in the project as a read-only dictionary and is placed in the root project directory. It will not be changed. It is not in my repository now, since I added its name to `.gitignore`.

Now I want to upload this project on github. Since a json-file is listed in `.gitignore` I expect that it will not be `push`ed to github repository. How to properly deal with such a file? Should I add it in the repository or not? Are there specific steps for configuration of a repository with such files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the big json file is needed by all users of your repository, I can see three options:

1. commit the file
2. write a program that can generate the json file on demand
3. instruct your users to download the file from some external place

Option #1 - Since the file won't change, anyone cloning the repository will only pay a one-time 45M file storage cost, which is required anyway since they need to be able to access the whole file.  In addition, the file will be compressed in git's db, so you won't have to pay double storage cost.  And clone only has to copy the compressed version of the file, so it will be faster than you think.

Option #2 - If the file is required for all users of your repository, and it's easy to generate, then just commit a program that generates the file, and give your users easy instructions on how to run that program.

Option #3 - Post the file somewhere and have your users download it, commit instructions in the README.

Option #1 seems most convenient, and 45M isn't very big, especially if the file isn't changing, so if it were me, I'd just commit the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable compression on specific files by adding to *.gitattribute* the following line:

```
*.<file extension> -crlf -diff -merge -delta
```

Comment: So, I need to add this big file to the local repository, then add the specified line in .gitattribute and push the repository on github?